# How to fetch user's First Name in php using Gmail Credentials as input?

Tags: php, forms, gmail-imap, imap-open

I earlier used imap_open function in php to validate credentials of users from a form and give them login to my website.
Now I also want to print their name that can be fetched from Google Servers providing their credentials as input.

I want to Print something like "Hello $gmail->firstname to the website", 
by providing the same user credentials from form as input to php file.

Is there anyway to do this without using Open ID API ?

My php function to authenticate was similar to this:-

```
function validate($username,$password) {
    $username = strtolower($username);
    $server="{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}";
    $result=false;
    $result = imap_open($server,$username,$password);
    if($result) {
            return 1;
    }
    else {
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try php's [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
$string_array = explode("@",$string);
echo $string_array[0];
```

has ur answer.

Comment: I think this function has to do with extraction, i was asking code similar to used in Google Open ID.